# Content Organizer Rulers For Folder Based Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, folder

> *I am thinking that I already know the answer to my questions, but am hoping that I am wrong.*

Can I setup a `Content Organizer Rule` on a Content Type based on a folder? So a `folder content type`, **NOT** a `document content type`.

I want to be able to move a folder full of documents, from a "*current*" lib to a "*former*" lib based on an "*active*" piece of metadata on my custom `folder content type`.

I have a feeling that this is not possible, as when building rules, I am only allowed the preset and custom `document content type` options and not any folder options what so ever.

Thanks SP Community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

Your feeling is right that it is not possible to setup a Content Organizer Rule based on a folder.

The Content Organizer can automatically do the following tasks:

[image]

Comment: Dang! Well thanks for digging that up for me anyways. Much aprech!

Comment: I am glad to help you.